# Left Join SQL Query - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join two tables Table1 and Table2 using the query below. I want all the columns (and rows) from Table1 and Column 'BasedOnDate' from Table2.
The problem is, all the values in column 'BasedOnDate' are being set to 1 after the left join, instead of on the rows where is a match in both the tables (likes row 1 in Table1 and Row 1 in Table2. Can someone comment on where the problem lies?

The query I am using right now:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.BasedOnDate
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.Name = Table2.Name) AND 
(Table1.[Date-4] = Table2.[Date-4]) AND 
(Table1.[Date-3] = Table2.[Date-3]) AND 
(Table1.[Date-2]= Table2.[Date-2]) AND 
(Table1.[Date-1] = Table2.[Date-1]) AND 
(Table1.ID = Table2.ID) AND 
(Table1.Site = Table2.Site);



Table2:

Site    ID     Date-1    Date-2     Date-3     Date-4    Name      BasedOnDate
00001   201    3/30/2011 4/6/2011   4/3/2011   4/6/2011  Name-1         1


Table1:

Site    ID     Date-1    Date-2     Date-3     Date-4    Name      
00001   201    3/30/2011 4/6/2011   4/3/2011   4/6/2011  Name-1
00001   101    5/21/2011 5/28/2011  5/21/2011  5/28/2011 Name-2
```

Comment: Is `Table2.Date-4` supposed to be the date minus four or is the name of your column `Date-4`. In the case of the latter you need to enclose those columns in brackets a la `Table2.[Date-4]`

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a where clause somewhere?  Can you include the actual results in the question?

Comment: I am confused by this statement "all the values in column 'BasedOnDate' are being set to 1 after the left join" as the value in the sample data is 1?

Comment: In Access `Name` is a reserved word so should be surrounded in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

As I recreated your situation I can confirm that using correct syntax the query works: retreives all column of `Table1` plus the joined `Table2`'s `BasedOnDate`. Where there's no match the query returns `null` for `BasedOnDate`.

```
SITE ID     DATE1           DATE2           DATE3           DATE4           NAME    BASEDONDATE
1    201    March, 30 2011  April, 06 2011  April, 03 2011  April, 06 2011  Name-1  1
1    101    May, 21 2011    May, 28 2011    May, 21 2011    May, 28 2011    Name-2  (null)
```

You can check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a56ee/2

If you need further research pls take a comment. Hope it helps you!

Comment: The OP already indicates in their post that they expected that the query should work. So what you've posted here is merely a statement of the obvious. This would be good as a comment, to confirm that the OP was correct in their expectation. It *might* have been fine as an answer if you could at least use an **MS Access** demo. That would partly address the actual question ("where the problem lies?") and show that the issue at least was not to do with MS Access in general. As it is, however, there's really little value to your answer at the moment.